# Plotting points with error bars from different dataframes ggplot R

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I have 3 dataframes one with actual data and others with upper and lower limits data respectively.
How can I combine these dataframes and create a scatter plot on ggplot with **error bars** (where the upper and lower limit data serve as the bars)?

Here is the example of the data and plotting code

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

DT <- data.frame(Samples=c("D1", "D2", "D3", "D4"),
             ACE=c(0.184, -0.169, 0.054, 0.087),
             FLN=c(-0.257, -0.239, -0.009, 0.038),
             ANT=c(-0.166, -0.304, 0.238, "" ),
             stringsAsFactors=FALSE)



 LowerLim <- data.frame(Samples=c("D1", "D2", "D3", "D4"),
              ACE=c(-1.514, "", -1.644, -1.611),
              FLN=c("", "", "", -1.660),
              ANT=c(-1.865, -2.003, 1.937, ""),
              stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

 UpperLim <- data.frame(Samples=c("D1", "D2", "D3", "D4"),
                   ACE=c(-0.560, "", -0.689,-0.657),
                   FLN=c("", "", "", -0.706),
                   ANT=c(-0.911,-1.049,0.983, "" ),
                   stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

 DTlong <- gather(DT, Cds, Values, "ACE":"ANT", factor_key=TRUE)

DTlong$Samples <- as.character(DTlong$Samples)

DTlong$Samples <- factor(DTlong$Samples, levels=unique(DTlong$Samples))

ggplot(DTlong)+geom_point(aes(color=Samples, y=Values, x=Cds))+
     theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())+ 
     theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=7, angle=90,hjust=0.95,vjust=0.2))+
    ggtitle("Points")
```

Comment: Your first data frame, containing the values, has higher values than the upper limit data frame. Have you got these round the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues here. Firstly, some of your columns are in character format rather than numeric format because you have put missing values as `""` rather than `NA`. I appreciate that this might look more natural when printing the data frame to the screen, but it means any column containing `""` is no longer numeric, and can't be used for calculations or plotting the values the column appears to contain.

That means the first step should be converting the three value columns in each data frame to numeric values:

```r
DT[-1] <- lapply(DT[-1], as.numeric)
LowerLim[-1] <- lapply(LowerLim[-1], as.numeric)
UpperLim[-1] <- lapply(UpperLim[-1], as.numeric)
```

The second issue is that your `DT` data frame and `UpperLit` data frame appear to be round the wrong way, since all of the values in DT are higher than the values in `UpperLimit`. For the purposes of this answer, I've had to assume this is a mistake. If your real data doesn't have this problem, you can omit this step:

```r
tmp <- DT
DT <- UpperLim
UpperLim <- tmp
rm(tmp)
```

The third issue is that the data are in the wrong shape to be plotted. Since the row and column orders are all the same, we can achieve this by pivoting each data frame into long format, and just keeping the value column from the upper and lower lim data frames.

```
df <- cbind(pivot_longer(DT, -1, names_to = "Cds", values_to = "Values"),
            lower = pivot_longer(LowerLim, -1)$value,
            upper = pivot_longer(UpperLim, -1)$value)
```

Now we are ready to plot. We will need to use `position_dodge` on both the points and the error bars to spread them out:

```
ggplot(df, aes(Cds, Values, color = Samples)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.5), size = 3) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), width = 0.25, size = 1,
                position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank()) +
  ggtitle("Points")
```

[image]